# How to store each digit of integer in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, integer

Let's say I have an integer `score = 345`. How do I store each digit seperatly in an array?

This is what I want:

```
ScoreValue[0] = 5
ScoreValue[1] = 4
ScoreValue[2] = 3
```

Or if there's any other way to access each digit seperatly with JS that might work too (I'm a newb at this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
ScoreValue = String(score).split(''); // gives you ['3', '4', '5']
ScoreValue = String(score).split('').reverse(); // gives you ['5', '4', '3']
```

If you want the element still be number, then

```
// gives you [5, 4, 3]
ScoreValue = String(score).split('').reverse().map(function(e) {return +e;});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your number into a string, and then split it up, before manipulating the resulting array...

```
var score = 345    
ScoreValue = score.toString().split('').reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. Using a for loop, force the score to a String then store each digit as a Number in ScoreVaue[i]

```
for(i=0;i<String(score).length;i++){ScoreValue[i] = Number(String(score).charAt(i))}
```